# Вывод количества вхождений в строку

Tags: javascript

Почему циклиться и не выводит?

```
function posik(a,b,s,d){
    var cnt = 0;
    var end = s+d;
    while((s=a.indexOf(a,s+1)) != end ){
    cnt++;
    }
  console.log( cnt );
  }
```

posik('Я снова снова снова тебя убить готов','нов',5,10);

Comment: @msim, не проверял работу, но точно вижу одно упущение:

    // у вас
    s=a.indexOf(a,s+1)
    // нужно
    s=a.indexOf(b,s+1)

Comment: ok, но как выводит, но меняю 10 на 15 и опять в цикл побежал.

Comment: @msim, на каком-то этапе, indexOf вернет вам "-1". Значит условие "**-1 != end**" - true и поехали по дальше до бесконечности.

    while((s=a.indexOf(b,s+1)) != end && s != -1){
      cnt++;
    }

Comment: то есть indexOf возвращает либо цифру на которой остановился либо -1 когда строка закончилась? он не может иди  посимвольно и сверяться с END?

Comment: @msim, читаем второе предложение в по [этой ссылке][1]

   [1]:http://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#indexof-lastindexof

Comment: спасибо прозрел, он возвращает b если нашел, если не нашел -1, но тогда как он становиться равен end, с != -1 все понятно

Comment: а чем не устраивает split ?

Comment: вы имеете в виду разбить на массив а дальше искать?

Comment: @msim, а дальше считать. Считать количество элементов в массиве -1

Comment: @msim

    > "attbttctt".split(/tt/).length
    4

Comment: @msim

    > "attbttctt".match(/tt/g).length
    3